# Length Group By não funciona

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou utilizando essa funçao para agrupar uns dados que vem da API:

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    var key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}


var groupedYear = groupBy(this._data, 'year');
```

Trás os dados corretamente, neste caso ele trás o ano 2020 e 2021;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu dou um `console.log(groupedYear.length);` ele retorna undefined.
Eu preciso que ele me retorne os dois itens, que é o 2020, e 2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso a variável `groupedYear` não é uma array, mas sim um objeto.

Apenas arrays possuem a propriedade `length`.

Você quer saber quantas chaves esse objeto possui, certo? Então você pode usar a função [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), que retorna um array com todas as chaves do objeto.

```
const length = Object.keys(groupedYear).length;
```

Comment: Deu certinho, estou apenas esperando o tempo para aceitar a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: E como faço pra pegar o length dentro do 2020 por exemplo? pra dar os 13 ?

Comment: @Mariana nesse caso só usar `groupedYear['2020'].length`.